# Trying to locate TraceLogger.Tracing.dll for Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, msmq

I'm migrating some legacy web services from a Server 2008 to Server 2016. The installation and set up of the web services are done using a PoweShell script and on the Server 2008 it utilises the TraceLogger.Tracing.dll to configure a ListenerNode for MSMQLogging. I can't find any reference to the TraceLogger.Tracing.dll file on the Server 2016 machine.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for installing this dll ?